# Laravel api response status always same as body

Tags: json, laravel, api

I am sending response of laravel API as

```
if(...){
        $return_array['status'] = '200';
        $return_array['message'] = 'OTP SEND';
    } else {
        $return_array['status'] = '400';
        $return_array['message'] = 'Username and Mobile Combination is Wrong';
    }
    return $this->response($return_array,200);
```

but response status is always 400

image attached

[image]

Comment: Your `if` condition always results in `false`

Comment: return statement @porloscerrosΨ is sending status 200 yet 400 got in response issue is this

Comment: Ohh... ok. Add this return inside the `else`:  `return $this->response($return_array,400);`

Comment: Or you can do `return $this->response($return_array,$return_array['status']);`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ i have to send status 200 in both cases and body status 200 in only first case

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ body status inside return_array but it is overwriting response($return_array,200); and sending 400 see image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213947/discussion-between-phpdroid-and-porloscerros-).

Comment: In the image you published, appears the result of the `else`, and not the result of the `if` with wrong 'status' field, if the condition were `true`, the response 'message' would be 'OTP SEND' and not 'Username and Mobile Combination is Wrong'.
Also you are missing a quote on $return_array['message'] = 'OTP SEND;

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the quote in this line

```
$return_array['message'] = 'OTP SEND;
```

replace it by

```
$return_array['message'] = 'OTP SEND';
```

Comment: it was dummy text i added for question aand missed the quote